# how do I disable specific mobs naturally spawning from mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do I disable specific parts of a mod; more specifically how do I stop specific mobs from spawning?

I have tried the bad mobs mod, but it doesn't work. The mod is Modern Warfare mod, I only want the guns, not natural enemy spawn in survival! I have gone through SO many posts and they don't answer my question. I have searched through google SO much and cant find anything.

Comment: why do people downvote my question idk what im doing wrong

Comment: If it's fixed, answer your question.  Don't put it as part of the title.

Comment: We don't do things like fixed or accepted. There's no reason to put it in the title. If you want to accept your answer, click the little checkmark beside your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a detailed explanation:

- First, find your Minecraft 'Instances' folder. To do this, right-click on your Minecraft shortcut, and click 'Open File Location'. From there, you can go back to your 'Minecraft' folder and you should see your 'Instances' folder.
- Go into that folder, and go into your mod folder.
- Go into the 'config' folder and find the .cfg file for the mod that contains the mob you want to stop spawning.
- Right-click it, click 'Open With', and choose Notepad or any other text editor. Look through the file until you find the setting for the mob you're looking for, and change the spawning value to 0.
- Save the file and you should be good.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i figured it out after another 1 hour and what feels like 30 more minutes of research i found a little comment giving a small suggestion and it was right so you go into your .minecraft folder (located in roaming) and then config then find the file and remove or edit the natural spawn rate. That's it

Comment: You can mark your answer as accepted to indicate that it's solved for you.

Comment: sorry i tried but it wouldnt let me edit it idk why

Comment: You don't need to edit it, there's a checkmark under the vote buttons.